# Uploading photos using dropzone.js working 1/5 times on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, dropzone.js

When using Dropzone for photo uploads on iPhone, the upload dialog opens when you tap the Dropzone element, but only inserts the image about 1 out of 5 times. This issue happens on both Chrome and Safari browsers on iPhone, but does not happen on iPad, desktop, or Android devices.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='dropbox' id='dropbox'>
  <div class='dz-message dropbox-message'>
    <div class='icon'>
      <img src='icon.png' alt='Upload Icon' />
    </div>
    <div class='description'>Upload photo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function randomString(len) {
    var rdmString = "";
    for (; rdmString.length < len; rdmString += Math.random().toString(36).substr(2));
    return rdmString.substr(0, len);
  }

  var cleanFilename = function(name) {
    var filename = name,
      extension = filename.split('.').pop(),
      random_string = randomString(28),
      new_file_name = random_string + '.' + extension;

    return new_file_name;
  };
  if ($('div#dropbox').length) {
    var profileImage = new Dropzone("div#dropbox", {
      url: "upload.php",
      paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
      clickable: '.dropbox *',
      acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
      resizeWidth: 600,
      maxFilesize: 10, // MB
      thumbnailWidth: 560,
      thumbnailHeight: 560,
      renameFilename: cleanFilename,
      maxFiles: 1,
      uploadMultiple: false,
      init: function() {
        console.log('Dropbox Initialized');
      }
    });
    profileImage.on('addedfile', function(file, errorMessage, xhr) {
      console.log("File Added");
      file.previewElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
        profileImage.removeFile(file);
      })
    })
    profileImage.on('error', function(file, errorMessage, xhr) {
      console.log(errorMessage + "\r\n" + file);
    })
  }

});
```

Dev console shows "Dropbox Initialized" message every time. The "File Added" message doesn't show except on the occasions it works. No errors are thrown in either instance.

jQuery version is 3.1.1. Dropzone version is 5.3.0.

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y9bghc5n/10/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by changing the `clickable: '.dropbox *'` line to `clickable: '.dropbox'`, removing the wildcard selector.

It looks like the JavaScript couldn't determine where the 'click' event was originating on iOS devices, and so the Dropzone object event listener would not receive the proper events unless the exact right part of the HTML element was tapped.

I believe it was related to [this issue](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/935), which led me down the right path.